# Fix flicker for dynamic layout in Next.js dyanmic import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am rendering a layout based on user configuration. A user may have headers, footer, etc. These configuration is read in when `_app` initializes.

When the header finally gets rendered, it pushes the main content down, causing most of the page to flicker. In addition, the header itself flickers on navigation.

I would like to have a finer control over the render to prevent any flickering on navigation. Navigating to the same page would still cause the page to flicker.

```
// _app
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Layout layout={layout}>
          <Component {...{ ...pageProps }} />
        </Layout>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </>
  );
```

```
// layout
const ComponentFactory = (props: IComponentProps): JSX.Element | null => {
  let Component = useMemo(
    () => (<Grid container></Grid>) as unknown as ComponentType,
    []
  );
  let args = useMemo(() => ({}), []);
  switch (props?.type) {
    case 'header':
      switch (props?.component) {
        case '1':
          Component = dynamic(() => import('./Header/HeaderA'));
          args = {
            logo: props?.logo
          };
          break;
      }
      break;
    case 'footer':
      switch (props?.component) {
        case '1':
          Component = dynamic(() => import('./Footer/FooterA'));
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
  return useMemo(() => <Component {...args} />, [Component, args]);
};

// Render
  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="row"
        alignContent={'space-between'}
      >
        {/* Top layout */}
        <Grid container spacing={0} item xs={12} zeroMinWidth>
          {/* Header */}
          {layout?.header?.component ? (
            <Grid
              item
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
              xs={12}
              zeroMinWidth
            >
              <ComponentFactory {...{ ...layout?.header }} />
            </Grid>
          ) : null}

          {/* Main content */}
          <Grid item zeroMinWidth>
            {children}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        {/* Bottom Layout */}
        {/* Footer */}
        {layout?.footer?.component ? (
          <Grid
            item
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
            xs={12}
            md={12}
            zeroMinWidth
          >
            <ComponentFactory {...layout?.footer} />
          </Grid>
        ) : null}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
```

---

**Update:**

I am able to remove the flicker if I skip the `ComponentFactory` step. So the issue is related to dynamic import or the extra function call.

---

**Update:**

The cause of the flicker appears to be `next/dynamic`. Strictly rendering the component would remove the flickering issue.

```
// Has flickering issue
case '1':
  Component = dynamic(() => import('./Footer/FooterA'));
  break;
// No flickering issue
case '1':
  return <FooterA></FooterA>;
```